# window.open doesn't work inside set setTimeout - popup blocked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to open a new window using window.open but with some delay. When I use setTimeout browsers shows popup blocked?.

DOES NOT WORK:

```
<a onclick="nextQuestion('https://www.google.com');">Gift</a>       

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
function nextQuestion(offer){
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.open('http://www.yahoo.com/','_blank'); 
        window.location = offer;
    }, 4000);
}
</script>
```

DOES WORK:

```
<a onclick="nextQuestion('https://www.google.com');">Gift</a>       

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
    function nextQuestion(offer){
            window.open('http://www.yahoo.com/','_blank'); 
            window.location = offer;
    }
    </script>
```

I have to open new tab window using window.open but inside setTimeout for some delay. Any alternate and work around would be much appreciated.

The objective is to open two pages, one inside same page and second in new tab but there is delay.

Comment: @RahulDesai that will block the entire browser tab for the delay period

Comment: @Rahul Desai, I just gave it a try and it also block the window.

Comment: @Arun P Johny, Yes, you are right. Is there any callback function when setTimeout is finished? So I can call back function for window.open?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cdosborn/mftcszwy/4/

Comment: @cdosborn, I didn't get your code?Any explanation.

Comment: It opens a window when you click on the link, no problem for me

Comment: @cdosborn, I need to open second window in new tab, so please use window.open with setTimeout and 4000 milliseconds.

Comment: updated, this is a browser config thing, you cannot circumvent this. It's a user respect default. It's not that your code "doesn't work", it's just the browser being courteous. All a user has to do is make an exception for your site, and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this:

```
<a onclick="setTimeout(nextQuestion('https://www.google.com'), 4000);">Gift</a>
```